# Need to send email to all users in database with one button?

Tags: php, database, function, email, pdo

I have managed by some miracle to send emails to a single user from the database. And I thought sending it to all users would be a no-brainer. However, all the research on google that I did are using mysqli which I am not using. I need this done via PHP PDO instead.

Here is what I have so far, but it just isn't working. I am have managed to get my users emails in a drop down menu which I am proud of, and I am trying to include one option, named : All emails or All users. Which if selected and submit the information will send this email to all users in my database.

```
<?php include('templates/navbar.php'); ?> <!-- include statement used to insert a part of the html document, not to waste time editing all the pages one by one, instead i can just edit one and it will apply to them all if i include it -->
<?php 
$dbHost = "localhost";
/** hostname of my database */
$dbUser = "root";
/** user name of my database */              /** These are all variables that have been declared */
$dbPassword = "root";
/** password of my database */
$dbName = "comp1321";
/** database name */


/** Connection to my database using the PDO method */
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $dbHost . ";dbname=" . $dbName;
    /** Example: $dbHost will take the hostname of "localhost" from the declared variables */
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "DB Connection Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    /** this is a error message in case the database did not connect, it will show on the website */
}


    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT emailAddress from user');
    $query->execute(); /** Executing query */
    $results = $query->fetchAll(); /** assigning results to the query which will fetch all data that adhere to that query */
?>

<?php
$message_sent = false;
if(isset($_POST['emailAddress']) && $_POST['emailAddress'] != ''){
   
if( filter_var($_POST['emailAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
    // submit the form
    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $userMessage = $_POST['Message'];
    
    
    $to = (implode " ," $emailAddress);
    $body = "";
    
    $body .= "From: ".$userName. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Username: ".$userName. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Message: ".$userMessage. "\r\n";
    
    mail($to,$emailAddress, $body);
    $message_sent = true;
    }
}

?>


<section class="main">
    <div class="contactbox">
        <form class="contact-font" method="POST" action="">
            <!-- creates a contact form with post method which will be included in the next coursework for the php insertion of data into database -->
            <br>
            <label for="emailAddress" class="required">Email Address</label> <!-- this is the label of the first input field -->
            <br><br>
            <select name="emailAddress" id="">
                <?php foreach ($results as $r) {
           echo "<option>";
            echo $r['emailAddress'];
           echo "</option>";
        } ?>
            <option value="All emails">
            <?php  $results['emailAddress'];?>
            </option>
            </select>

            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="userName" class="required">Username</label>
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="inputStyle" placeholder="Username" required>
                <!-- this input type is an email, which will make sure the user enters an email with a @ -->
            </div>
            <br>
            <label for="Message" class="required text-align-center">Message</label>
            <div class="">
                <textarea id="Message" name="Message" wrap="soft" class="inputStyle" placeholder="Your message..." rows="6" maxlength="3000" required></textarea>
                <!-- text area used for long messages, with a soft wrap which will not break up any long words, with a max word length of 3000 words -->
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="text-align-center">
                <button type="submit" id="" class="button-contact">Send Message</button>
                <!-- submit button which allows user to submit form -->
            </div>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>

<?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?> <!-- include statement used to insert a part of the html document, not to waste time editing all the pages one by one, instead i can just edit one and it will apply to them all if i include it -->
```

Comment: Depending upon the number of recipients to which you want to send the emails the native PHP method `mail` may not prove to be the best option. From the manual, it states: `"It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient. "`

Comment: If I have interpreted your code correctly it seems you are hoping to select, from the dropdown menu, **all** users as specified by the `text` value `$results['emailAddress']` in the dropdown menu and then POST the form in the hope that the PHP script will take that value and send to all email address in that value? If that is the case then you have additional steps to take.

Comment: The value held by `$results = $query->fetchAll();` will be an array but you are trying to echo that within the HTML ( are there no errors?? ) so you cannot simply `echo` it directly. The value of the submitted option would be `All emails` because it is the `value` that gets submitted - not the text.